# Vino only shows background

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, vino

I am having an issue doing Remote Desktop (or vnc) to my ubuntu 17.04 machine (as well as my 16.10) I tried using tightvnc, and was successfully able to forward only a terminal window, and also successfully break gnome shell to the point where I couldn't login. I fixed that, and then I tried using Vino. After doing the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

I am actually able to get a remote connection (I am trying the connection from both my MacBook and my iPad) The only problem is that all the remote connection shows is the login screen wallpaper. I can see and move the mouse and if I am viewing the Ubuntu machine and I click the mouse on the remote client I can see it clicking the mouse on the actual desktop.

**My question is:** How can I get a successful Remote Desktop connection to my Ubuntu? 
I am not too worried about which desktop gets forwarded, be it: unity, gnome, gnome flashback, or mate, I just need one that works. (Im not much of a fan of xfce or lxde but if I must use them I will)

This is all happening on a virtualized test machine, so it doesn't really matter if anything gets broken, if I can't fix it I can just restore a snapshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue. My Ubuntu 17.04 VM was pretty messed up and it was easier just to abandon it and start fresh. I installed a fresh VM of Ubuntu Gnome 17.04. After the install I ran the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

Then I ran

```
vino-passwd
```

and set a password.

My connection didn't work after turning sharing on in vino preferences, so I went into

**System Settings - Sharing**

and Turned on sharing, and screen sharing. After this I initiated a connection from my iPad and it worked. I am not sure if the vino-passwd was required or if I should of even bothered with vino-preferences.

Seems to me like just enabling screen sharing in the sharing preferences of gnome did it on an un-altered installation.

Comment: Now I need to try and get it to work before I login

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen once and it came down to issues with `compiz`. Disabling Desktop Effects may also help: **System -> Preferences -> Appearances-> Visual Effects**

As far as alternative clients, I use and recommend [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/).

Comment: Disabling visual effects didn't help (in unity at least) I'm locked out of gnome currently (login loop). However I will look into FreeRDP tomorrow when I have some time to figure it out and let you know my results.

Comment: Do you recall what compiz issues you fixed in order to resolve the issue?